# How to launch a xamarin app on iOS simulator from windows?

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin

I have build a xamarin app and tested it on android emulator and the app works fine. I've decided to test it on iOS simulator, but it is not going as planed. I've connected my windows pc to the MacBook Pro, updated Visual Studio 2019 and xCode to the latest version and set the Automatic Provisioning. When I try to launch the app on ios 14.5 version of no importance which iPhone, I get this error:

```
error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'packageName' on the device 'iOS 14.5 (18E182) - iPhone 12': ???appName??? Needs To Be Updated
```

I've google it with no success. I've tried to launch the app on older iOS version, but I get another error:

```
error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'packageName' on the device 'iOS 13.0 (17A577) - iPhone 8': The request to open "appName" failed.
```

I've checked the logs on the macBook simulator, but I still can't solve my issue.

Logs from  iPhone 8 iOS 13.0 simulator:

```
Jul  1 16:02:11 Borjans-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.7E33AFBE-858C-4EBD-9470-8E503EAA0B21[18503] (UIKitApplication:packageName[82f8][rb-legacy][38282]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 86: Bad CPU type in executable: /Users/borjan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E33AFBE-858C-4EBD-9470-8E503EAA0B21/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B178901C-355F-4956-9EA0-296A2CEB1718/projectName.iOS.app/projectName.iOS
Jul  1 16:02:11 Borjans-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.7E33AFBE-858C-4EBD-9470-8E503EAA0B21[18503] (UIKitApplication:bundleName[82f8][rb-legacy][38282]): Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
Jul  1 16:02:11 Borjans-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.7E33AFBE-858C-4EBD-9470-8E503EAA0B21[18503] (UIKitApplication:bundleName[82f8][rb-legacy][38282]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
Jul  1 16:02:59 Borjans-MBP syslogd[18505]: ASL Sender Statistics
```

I've spend a few days looking for solution but I didn't find one. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you want to see the UI of app in windows or macBook ?

Comment: I’ve tried displaying the emulator on windows, I’ve got an error: the device “GUID” is not found. Then I unchecked "Remote Simulator to Windows." and I’ve got the error already provided in the question.

Comment: I've also created new xamarin project just to test it and it was launched on the iPhone simulator on the macBook. I've also compared the configurations on both projects and they are the same... Still can find why the app can't launch.

Comment: `I’ve tried displaying the emulator on windows, I’ve got an error: the device “GUID” is not found.` yes,it is a known issue , you can check it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-1694-cannot-connect-to-ios-simulator-xcode/1412563?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1466752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found what was the issue. It somehow the configuration changes from iPhoneSimulator to iPhone when I am clicking the run button. I should manually set the configuration to iPhoneSimulator and it works now. Just go to Configuration Manager, find the iOS project and set the platform to iPhoneSimulator instead of iPhone.